# Why the scala :_* to expand a Seq into variable-length argument list does not work in this case?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

Why the scala `:_*` to expand a Seq into variable-length argument list does not work in this case?

and how to solve it elegantly?

```
import java.sql.Connection
import scalikejdbc.ConnectionPool
import anorm.{SQL, SqlQuery, SqlRow, Row}

object AnormExample extends App {
  Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver")
  ConnectionPool.singleton("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:hsqldb:WithAnorm", "", "")
  implicit val conn: Connection = ConnectionPool.borrow()

  // this works
  SQL("insert into emp (id, name) values ({id}, {name})").onParams(3, "name3").executeUpdate()  

  // this does not compile
  val row = Seq(4, "name4")
  SQL("insert into emp (id, name) values ({id}, {name})").onParams(row:_*).executeUpdate()  // david
}
```

error:

```
scala: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Any]
 required: Seq[anorm.ParameterValue[?]]
  SQL("insert into emp (id, name) values ({id}, {name})").onParams(row:_*).executeUpdate()  // david
```

ps:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>play</groupId>
  <artifactId>anorm_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.seratch</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalikejdbc_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

any elegant solution?

**Update**

based on the answer from senia, this solves the problem:

```
def toParameterValueSet(seq: Seq[Any]) = seq.map(v => v: anorm.ParameterValue[_])
val row = Seq(5, "name5")
SQL("insert into emp (id, name) values ({id}, {name})").onParams(toParameterValue(row):_*).executeUpdate()
```

is there a way to remove the need for declaring/using toParameterValueSet?

(for instance, to tell scala to use the implicit conversion on the automatic expansion `:_*`)

**Update**

a bit more compact:

```
implicit def toParameterValueSet(seq: Seq[Any]): Seq[anorm.ParameterValue[_]] = seq.map(v => v: anorm.ParameterValue[_])
val row = Seq(5, "name5")
SQL("insert into emp (id, name) values ({id}, {name})").onParams(row:_*).executeUpdate()
```

@Typesafe team: could you add a parameter on acrom SQL to take a seq of values?
(instead having to use :_*)
(I agree that using named parameters is preferred, but sometimes it is still useful to have unnamed parameters)

Answer (score 3):

You could try to replace

```
val row = Seq(4, "name4")
```

with

```
val row = Seq[anorm.ParameterValue[_]](4, "name4")
```

there are implicit conversions for all types, so you can convert you collection using `row.map{ e => e: anorm.ParameterValue[_] }`

Comment: the problem is not there is no implicit conversion form Any to anorm.ParameterValue. replacing with 'val row: Seq[String] = Seq("hello", "world")' does not work either. it seems that the problem is that the implicit conversion when using the expansion.

Comment: your proposition works. however, we are just moving the problem: how to convert a Seq("hello", "world") to a Seq[anorm.ParameterValue[_]]("hello", "world"). we could use the map function, to convert each param; but is it really not possible to use the automatic expansion?

Comment: @DavidPortabella: If you have a `Seq[String]` you could convert it to `Seq[anorm.ParameterValue[_]]` using `seq.map{s => s: anorm.ParameterValue[_]}`, but if you have Seq[Any] the type information is lost and you can't create `ParameterValue`.

Comment: @DavidPortabella: there is implicit conversion from all types to anorm.ParameterValue. It was my mistake. You can convert your collection when you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the `type`. The `<:` defines a type bound.

```
A <: B
```

Says A must be bound by type B, or any A is a subtype of B. Give that `row:_*` a proper `type` bound. I think `String` bounds work. `anorm.ParameterValue[String]`.

To be more specific, `val row = Seq[anorm.ParameterValue[_]](4, "name4")`. This should perform the `implicit` conversion.